# как получить данные с api по частям?

Tags: ios, swift, api

мне нужно читать данные с API до определенного момента, данные идут байтами, каждые 21 байт составляют одну запись. Если загружать все сразу - выходит очень долго, так как полный размер равен примерно 1,6 мб
[image: Скриншот]
Собственно вопрос: как получать данные по 21 байту?
Сейчас у меня такой долго загружающий код:

```
func getLogBinData() {
    if let url = URL(string: httpString + "log.bin") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                print()
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Дополнено:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate {
    
    var task = URLSessionDataTask()
    
    var httpString = "http://134.17.24.191/"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getLogBinData()
    }
    
    
    func getLogBinData() {
        if let url = URL(string: httpString + "log.bin") {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        if dataTask.countOfBytesReceived >= 500 {
            print(dataTask.countOfBytesReceived)
        }
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    dataTask: URLSessionDataTask,
                    didReceive response: URLResponse,
                    completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        if dataTask.countOfBytesReceived >= 500 {
            print(dataTask.countOfBytesReceived)
        }
    }
    
}
```

делегатные методы не срабатывают вовсе, что не так? и как мне вернуть в делегатном методе, который вы посоветовали полученные на данный момент данные?

Comment: "делегатные методы не срабатывают вовсе" - конечно, потому что не соблюдено - "Создаете свою сессию". `URLSession.shared` ничего не знает о вашем делегате.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, что поменять, как правильно прописать?

Comment: Этот вопрос не так прост, чтобы набросать и готово. Поэтому либо вы разбираетесь самостоятельно, любо бросайте и гуглите какую-нибудь библиотеку, которая это умеет.

Answer (score 0):

Сам не делал, но как-то так:

- Создаете свою сессию с помощью https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411597-init
- В нее передаете имплементацию URLSessionDataDelegate, где в методе https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate/1410027-urlsession можно конвертировать URLSessionDataTask в URLSessionStreamTask
- А в методе https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate/1411648-urlsession получите экземпляр URLSessionStreamTask

Дальше думаю разберетесь.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionstreamtask

Comment: не до конца понимаю, если есть время, набросайте код.
смысл следующий, я начну парсить, когда получу некоторое количество байт, например больше или равно 210, по 21 байту начну их сверять с теми записями, которые хранятся в моих логах, и как только я дойду до полученной записи, которая уже хранится у меня в логах, я хочу прекратить принимать данные